# Nice Syntaxe for creating new object from method

Tags: php, coding-style

There is a shortcut method to create an object from a method that return a string?

For the moment, I used that :

```
class MyClass {

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityName() {
        return 'myEntityName';
    }
}

$myClassInstance = new MyClass();

// Need to get string
$entityName = $myclassInstance->getEntityName();

// And after I can instantiate it
$entity = new $entityName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is short-cut syntax for getting the string but not for creating the object from the string to date in PHP.  See the following code in which I also include a 'myEntityName' class:

```
<?php

class myEntityName {
    public function __construct(){
        echo "Greetings from " . __CLASS__,"\n";
    }
}
class MyClass {

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityName() {
        return 'myEntityName';
    }
}

$entityName = ( new MyClass() )->getEntityName();
$entity = new $entityName();
```

With one line the code instantiates a MyClass object *and* executes its getEntityName method which returns the string $entityName. Interestingly, if I replace my one-liner with the following it fails in all versions of PHP except for the HipHop Virtual Machine (hhvm-3.0.1 - 3.4.0):

```
$entityName = new ( ( new MyClass() )->getEntityName() );
```

Comment: The last shortcut is close to my needs ^^. `$entityName = ( new MyClass() )->getEntityName();` is a new feature of php5.4. My need/interesting point is to shortcut the instantiation. thx.